# creating python virtual env on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-venv

I'm new to Linux environment where i need to create a virtual environment for my project. As this is a development machine i will not have access like i used to have in my own machine. I tried running the below commands :

```py
    python3 -m venv env
```

But got permission denied:

I tried using sudo su command upon which it asked to enter my password. Later it said "Sorry, user xxxx is not allowed to execute 'usr/bin/su' as root on

Is this meant i do not have access to run sudo command?

Comment: "*Is this meant i do not have access to run sudo command?*" I mean, that's almost exactly what it says. You need to include *all* pertinent information here, including the full stack trace of the error you get when attempting to run the command you provided.

Comment: if I'm not totally mistaken venv shouldn't require sudo. Did you check that you have rights for creating a "env" folder? Missing write permissions seem the most likely case too me

Comment: As a user on a Linux machine, you should have access to your own home directory (try `cd ~` to go there). Within this directory you should have adequate permissions to create files and sub-directories, including a python virtual environment. If you do not, then contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "permission denied" error is probably due to the fact that you are in a directory where you have no write rights

Solution:

1. either change directory (for instance with `cd`, this will take you to your `$HOME` where you certainly have write rights)

or

2. give a full path for directory where you want to save the virtual environment (for instance to save in `~/my_env` use `python3 -m venv ~/my_env`)

By issuing the command

```
python -m venv -h
```

you can see all the options of `venv`.

Answer (score 2):

if you run `python3 -m venv env` a virtual environment will be created in your current directory. As `venv` does not require admin privileges it seems more likely that you are trying to run the command in a directory where you don't have sufficient write permissions.